# Magento not allowing special characters like é

Tags: html, magento, utf-8

I have a `<select>` element with some options on a dropdown. on that dropdown i have product some of these product have names that come up eith special characters like é. But on the front-end instead of showing the é it shows the Ã¤ characters.

for solution I tried to use special characters like É for é inside a textfield. But when I replace the é with É inside a textfield, on the front-end it shows the É My magento store charset is utf8.

i want to use é, $, ä etc... of my Magento store. is there any way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to it
First You can check which language select in system->configuration->general tab
after you select English then  special characters not support.